# Unable to determine the relationship

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core

I am quite new within the .NET Entity Framework and currently, I am stuck when I am trying to implement some relationship between two entities. I am getting the following exception message:

> Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'Actor.ActiveMovies' of type 'ICollection'

I do not know how I correctly identify this relationship. The movie and actor entities are shown below.

**Movie.cs Entity**

```
    public class Movie
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid MovieId { get; set; }

        public string Title { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        public string ThumbnailUrl { get; set; }

        public string Language { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public virtual ICollection<Actor> Actors { get; set; }
    }
```

**Actor.cs Entity**

```
    public class Actor
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid ActorId { get; set; }

        public string ProfileImageUrl { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public DateTime BornDate { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Movie> ActiveMovies { get; set; }
    }
```

**What do I want to achieve**

It seems that movies and actors have a many to many relationship since a movie can have multiple actors and an actor can be active in multiple movies. Although I have not figured anything out to do this.

**What have I tried**

I have checked out the DatabaseContext and I thought I could implement a many to many as following.

```
            modelBuilder.Entity<Movie>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(movie => movie.MovieId);
                entity.Property(movie => movie.Actors).IsRequired();
                entity.HasMany<Actor>(movie => movie.Actors);
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<Actor>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(actor => actor.ActorId);
                entity.HasMany<Movie>(actor => actor.ActiveMovies);
            });
```

But this gave me the exception message

> The property or navigation 'Actors' cannot be added to the entity type 'Movie' because a property or navigation with the same name already exists on entity type 'Movie'.

I would appreciate any insight in this case!

Comment: A many to many relationship needs an allocation table instead of lists, and you refer both ActorId and MovieId in it (with other columns if you want, like played character name, role, whatever). With this you can create multiple entries for the same movie (different actors), and the same actor can be in multiple movies. It may be personal but I prefer create a new Entity than using lists and working with the ModelBuilder.

Answer (score 1):

You need to fully define The relationship. In this case we are using separate table. Try this.

```
 public class Movie
    {
        public Guid MovieId { get; set; }

        public string Title { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        public string ThumbnailUrl { get; set; }

        public string Language { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<MovieActor> MovieActors { get; set; }
    }



 public class Actor
    {
        public Guid ActorId { get; set; }

        public string ProfileImageUrl { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public DateTime BornDate { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<MovieActor> MovieActors { get; set; }
    }

  public class MovieActor
    {
   public int MovieId { get; set; }

   public Movie Movie { get; set; }

   public int ActorId { get; set; }

   public Actor Actor{ get; set; }
    }
```

and in your **OnModelCreating()**

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<MovieActor>()
            .HasKey(x=> new { x.ActorId, x.MovieId });  

       modelBuilder.Entity<MovieActor>()
            .HasOne(bc => bc.Movie)
            .WithMany(b => b.MovieActors)
            .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.MovieId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<MovieActor>()
            .HasOne(bc => bc.Actor)
            .WithMany(c => c.MovieActors)
            .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.ActorId);
```

Comment: I would add a specific Id (or Guid) to the `MovieActor` table and drop both ICollections.

Comment: That is also right ! , But corrected the code by his style. This will also work.

Comment: Ah okay cool that it works this way. I am going to test it out tomorrow. Does the new entity need both the Movie object and the MovieId? Or is that a mistake in the code snippet?

Comment: Of course it needs both Movie object and the MovieId. That's the main point of making a many to many relationship.

Answer (score 0):

EF core does not - yet, unfortunately - support many-to-many relationships without needing the relationship as a fully defined entity.

Coming in .net 5 and EF core 5.x is that feature which will roughly work like

```
 builder.Entity<Movie>()
        .HasMany(m=>m.Actions)
        .WithMany(a=>a.Movies); // Invented syntax, the feature has not been released yet.
```

For the time being you'll need to define the entity which maps MovieActor manually and map both sides of the one-to-many relationship it will model. I am eliding the definition for that entity here, just going to define the configuration below.

```
builder.Entity<MovieActor>()
       .HasKey(ma => new { ma.MovieId, ma.ActorId });

builder.Entity<Movie>()
       .HasMany(m=>m.MoiveActors)
       .WithOne(ma=>ma.Movie);

builder.Entity<Actor>()
       .HasMany(m=>m.MoiveActors)
       .WithOne(ma=>ma.Actor);
```